# Estimate how long it takes to get out of an airport

Tags: gratis, prediction

Whenever I have to fetch someone from the airport I usually arrive at the airport on the estimated arrival time, so I waste time in the arrival hall.
On the opposite, when I am the passenger, I would like to give my friends a reasonable meeting time so that they don't wait for me, but even with a margin it is hard to get it right.

I am looking for an app that a reasonable estimate how long it takes to get through. I would presumably have to input:

- Destination airport
- Origin airport
- Time of arrival
- Nationality
- Whether the passenger already has a visa or does not need one
- Class of travel
- Whether the passenger has anything to declare at customs
- Whether the passenger has any checked-in luggage
- Flight number (a perfect app would check for delays, identify whether the carousel has started delivering luggage, etc)

A rough estimate is OK, or better a low/average/high estimate.
Bonus if the app allows the user to press a button when the passenger arrives, sending data for the developers to improve the algorithm.

Requirements:

- Webapp or Android app
- Free, ideally open source

*Inspired from [travel.stackexchange.com](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34015/how-do-you-estimate-how-long-it-takes-to-get-out-of-an-airport)*

Comment: I would suggest that any current security flags in the country of arrival might also be relevant.